# select date diff from varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a the way to find the `DateDiff` of the `nvarchar` against `getdate` values:

```
create table dbo.DateChk
([DateString] [nvarchar](24) NULL)
insert into dbo.DateChk (DateString) values ('20130112'),('20131121'), ('20130924'),('20130515')

select getdate(), DateString 
---,  getdate()- DateString as DateDiff
from dbo.DateChk
```

Comment: Never, ever store dates in `varchar` columns.

Comment: Convert the date-varchars to DATE or DATETIME first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `DATEDIFF` function:

```
select getdate(), DateString 
---,  getdate()- DateString as DateDiff
, DATEDIFF(DAY,  DateString, getdate())
from dbo.DateChk
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx